# Pandas/Numpy shift rows into column based on existence

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe like so:

```
col_a | col b
  0      1
  0      2
  0      3
  1      1
  1      2
```

I want to convert it to:

```
col_a | 1 | 2 | 3
  0     1   1   1
  1     1   1   0
```

Unfortunately, most questions/answers revolving around this topic simply pivot it

Background: For Scikit, I want to use the existence of values in column b as an attribute/feature (like a sort of manual CountVectorizer, but for row values in this case instead of text)

Comment: @jezrael Oops, fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with creating first column to `index`, last use `max` per index for return only `1/0` values in output:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('col_a')['col b'], prefix='', prefix_sep='').max(level=0)

print (df)
       1  2  3
col_a         
0      1  1  1
1      1  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Groupby.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and use it as columns for a pivoted dataframe, which can be obtained using  [`pd.croostab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) and by default computes a frequency table of the factors  :

```
cols = df.groupby('col_a').cumcount()
pd.crosstab(index = df.col_a, columns = cols)

col_0  0  1  2
col_a         
0      1  1  1
1      1  1  0
```